# How to pivot on two levels

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot, relational-database

I am using SQL Server 2012 and am trying to construct a pivot table from TSQL based on the table below which has been generated by joining multiple tables.

```
INCIDENT ID | Department | Priority      | Impact 
--------------------------------------------
1           | IT         | Urgent        | High
2           | IT         | Retrospective | Medium   
3           | Marketing  | Normal        | Low
4           | Marketing  | Normal        | High
5           | Marketing  | Normal        | Med
6           | Finance    | Normal        | Med
```

From this table, want it to be displayed in following format:

```
Priority     | Normal              | Urgent              | Retrospective       |
| Department | Low | Medium | High | Low | Medium | High | Low | Medium | High |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| IT         |   1 |      1 |    0 |   1 |      1 |    0 |   1 |      1 |    0 |
| Finance    |   0 |      0 |    1 |   1 |      1 |    0 |   1 |      1 |    0 |
| Marketing  |   0 |      1 |    0 |   1 |      1 |    0 |   1 |      1 |    0 |
```

I have the following code which successfully Pivots on the "Priority" level.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(incident.incident_id) OVER(PARTITION BY serv_dept.serv_dept_n) Total,
        serv_dept.serv_dept_n       Department,
        ImpactName.item_n           Impact,
        PriorityName.item_n         Priority    
    FROM --  ommitted for brevity
    WHERE  -- ommitted for brevity
) AS T

PIVOT (
    COUNT(Priority)
    FOR Priority IN ("Normal", "Urgent", "Retrospective")
) PIV
ORDER BY Department ASC
```

How can I get this query to pivot on two levels like the second table I pasted?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your sample data has no "Finance" department.  Where does that information come from?

Comment: That is just random data I typed in for explanation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way may be conditional aggregation:

```
select department,
       sum(case when priority = 'Normal' and target = 'Low' then 1 else 0 end) as Normal_low,
       sum(case when priority = 'Normal' and target = 'Med' then 1 else 0 end) as Normal_med,
       sum(case when priority = 'Normal' and target = 'High' then 1 else 0 end) as Normal_high,
       . . .
from t
group by department;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at it:

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
    SELECT
        Department
        , Priority + '_' + Impact AS PriorityImpact
        , Incident_ID
    FROM
        <table>
)
SELECT
    Department
    , Normal_Low
    , Normal_Medium
    ,...
FROM
PivotData
PIVOT (COUNT(Incident_ID FOR PriorityImpact IN (<Listing all the PriorityImpact values>) ) as P;
```

Comment: Is this method portable to other databases?

Comment: The syntax of this is for TSQL. I don't know which other databases you mean. I think that must depend on if the vendor support PIVOT and the specific syntax for that vendor.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution. I assume the WITH clause you have is equiviliant with the select subquery I used in the OP. However I think I like Gordon Linoff's answer better.

Comment: I agree with you on that. I like Gordon's answer too. The only reason that I added this answer was because you seemed to ask for a pivot solution.